# How to get redirected to other html file on success ajax response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I need your help on how to get redirected to other html file on success ajax response in the javascript.

Below is my code where i am getting the successful ajax response in jsonvariable.

I have tried using window.location but its not working. is there any other way to do the same, Please let me know

```js
function myFunction() {

    $.ajax({
   url: '/ValidateOTP',
   type: 'POST',
   data:JSON.stringify( $('#OTP').val()),
   contentType: 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
   success: function(response){
       jsonvariable=response['success'].toString();
       if(jsonvariable=='true')
             alert('done');

       else if(jsonvariable=='false')
           document.getElementById("div2").innerHTML="OTP didn't match !! Please click the GET OTP button to re-generate OTP";
                    document.getElementById("div2").style.color="Red";

            },
   error: function(response){
           alert(response)

   }
  });
};
```

Comment: Why `window.location.href` or `window.location.replace` are not working?

Comment: I tried using those above methods but if i use it...my entire code is not working

Comment: If need i need to use a page called "homepage.html" in any of those methods how can i do it?

Comment: document.location.href="https://yourdomain.com/homepage.html";

Comment: i am doing at the local host then how the url will be?

Comment: @Trueman can you please confirm is it window.location.href or document.location.href?

Comment: it doesn't matter if you are not working in frame - window.location is mapped in document.location, people are arguing that window.location is "safer" but they don't know how to explain why ;) In theory window.location is bacward compatible with very old browsers, but very old browsers are out of the market today

Comment: It is worth to mention that sometimes window.location didn't worked for me - but suprisingly I had never any issues with document.location

Answer (score 1):

Use this function in after success:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    window.location.href = "http://www.google.com"";
});
```

Comment: use this function in after success

Comment: if i need to mention an html page for ex:mainpage.html how can i mention it?

Answer (score 1):

you can window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com'; or  window.location = 'http://google.com';

function myFunction() {

```
$.ajax({
        url: '/ValidateOTP',
        type: 'POST',
        data:JSON.stringify( $('#OTP').val()),
        contentType: 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
        success: function(response){
            jsonvariable=response['success'].toString();
            if(jsonvariable=='true'){
                window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com';
            }

            else if(jsonvariable=='false')
                document.getElementById("div2").innerHTML="OTP didn't match !! Please click the GET OTP button to re-generate OTP";
                document.getElementById("div2").style.color="Red";

        },
        error: function(response){
                alert(response)

        }
    });
```

};

Comment: Hey Amit, Thanks for this but if i need to mention some html page in local host how can i mention it? for example mainpage.html

Comment: you just need to specify controller action path like 'Home/mainpage and your tag will become '

window.location.href = '/Home/mainpage';

if you are working on .net MVC

Answer (score 1):

Since you're probably working in your domain (localhost in your case), you need to only add the file name you are linking to.`window.location.href = 'homepage.html';`
Resolve your file path based on your folder structure. See help https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)

Comment: @SheikAbdullah you have to resolve the path to the home page. Depending on your file structure, your path may look like this './homepage.html' or ../homepage.html. For more info, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)

Answer (score 1):

```
success: function (response) {
    if(jsonvariable=='true'){
    alert("redirect page to");
    window.location = "http://www.google.com/";
    }
},
failure: function (response) {
     alert(response.d);
}
```

Any valid Ajax request will return either a success or failure. As per above issue, on success we need to redirect to another page or url. Window.location function help to redirect to another page or url.